# converting CURL to postman

Tags: api, curl, postman

I'm trying to import the below cUrl command in "Paste Raw Text" option. Its getting Error - invalid format.

```
curl --insecure https://splunkbox.whc/en-US/splunkd/__raw/service -d username=suraj -d password=afjfkdf
```

the option "--insecure" is the problem. How can I pass this from the postman?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove `--insecure` from your raw text when you paste it.
You can set the insecure mode by File->Settings (General Tab)
Uncheck the "SSL Certificate verification"
[image]

Comment: I did the same like as above as you said. I already disabled SSL in postman. Its not working

Comment: Did you also remove ```--insecure``` from your curl command?
I was able to import the curl command into postman by leaving the ```--insecure``` parameter out

Comment: yes, after removing --insecure or -k option, its importing properly into postman. but after clicking "send", It says "Could not get any response"

Comment: hey thanks, issue got resolved. it was issue with splunk environment, that i'm accessing. thanks again!